# Neo4J graph visualisations in external application

Tags: neo4j

I would like to re-use my Neo4J graph visualisations (i.e. the ones displayed in the Neo4J browser) in an external Web application. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by the Neo4j Browser. You can export the images as SVG, but there is no feature that allows the visualization to be embedded in another web application.

Having said that, the Neo4j Browser is an open source application, the code is available here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser You can see how it works, for inspiration in implementing your own visualizations.

[This page](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) has an overview of some various network visualization options.